# Equivalent of JavaImport in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: java, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, packages

I've got ST2 on my Windows machine which I've installed the [JavaImport package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaImports) which is a great tool for automatically writing the 'import' statements for various functions.

Unfortunately it is not available for ST3 which is installed on my Mac and I was just wondering if there was an equivalent (easy) way to automatically write the import statements. I can't seem to find an equivalent via google...

Does Javatar offer this feature? If so how do you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Javatar can do this. It's within the Java Operations option on it's main menu. However it's not as quick and easy as one shortcut. However it does fix all of your imports instead of just importing for one specific function (which is what JavaImport did).